# Push notification not receiving when app is in background using parse

Tags: objective-c, background, parse-platform, xcode6, apple-push-notifications

Push notification not receiving  when app is in background .If application is in foreground it is working fine,if app in background after receiving notification need to start some process.

Here my code is :

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
     if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive)
    {
       NSLog(@" background userInfo =%@",userInfo);

        [PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload:userInfo];
    }

}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
                       didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    NSLog(@"%@",userInfo);

}
```

My Environment : `iOS8,Xcode 6.3,Mac10.10.`

Answer (score 0):

For iOS8 you need to use the second of the following delegate methods:

```
// < iOS7
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo

// >= iOS7
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
```